# How to add dark theme for `gridjs`

Tags: javascript, css, darkmode, gridjs

I am currently developing a single site that is in a dark theme and using `gridjs` to display data in a table. The problem is that the official settings are on the `light` theme and it seems that there is currently no support for the `dark` theme. I also read how to add `css` [`styles`](https://gridjs.io/docs/config/style) to a `Grid.js` instance + as well as how to add `css` [`classname`](https://gridjs.io/docs/config/className) to a `Grid.js` instance, but I didn't manage to solve it that way.

[image]

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to customize the gridjs table on a `dark` theme?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the compiled `.css` file, you can add a dark theme based on the device's current mode (light or dark) like this:
(i.e. using this `.css` file will keep the existing color scheme if the device is in `light` mode and invert the colors when it switches to `dark` mode)

```css
.gridjs-head button, .gridjs-footer button {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none; }

.gridjs-temp {
  position: relative; }

.gridjs-head {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 5px 1px; }
  .gridjs-head::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both; }

.gridjs-head:empty {
  padding: 0;
  border: none; }

.gridjs-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0; }

.gridjs-footer {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border-top: 1px solid #e5e7eb;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-color: #e5e7eb; }

.gridjs-footer:empty {
  padding: 0;
  border: none; }

input.gridjs-input {
  outline: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #d2d6dc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 13px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.45;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none; }
  input.gridjs-input:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(149, 189, 243, 0.5);
    border-color: #9bc2f7; }

.gridjs-pagination {
  color: #3d4044; }
  .gridjs-pagination::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both; }
  .gridjs-pagination .gridjs-summary {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5px; }
  .gridjs-pagination .gridjs-pages {
    float: right; }
    .gridjs-pagination .gridjs-pages button {
      padding: 5px 14px;
      border: 1px solid #d2d6dc;
      background-color: #fff;
      border-right: none;
      outline: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
         -moz-user-select: none;
          -ms-user-select: none;
              user-select: none; }
    .gridjs-pagination .gridjs-pages button:focus {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(149, 189, 243, 0.5); }
    .gridjs-pagination .gridjs-pages button:hover {
      background-color: #f7f7f7;
      color: #3c4257;
      outline: none; }
    .gridjs-pagination .gridjs-pages button:disabled,
    .gridjs-pagination .gridjs-pages button[disabled],
    .gridjs-pagination .gridjs-pages button:hover:disabled {
      cursor: default;
      background-color: #fff;
      color: #6b7280; }
    .gridjs-pagination .gridjs-pages button.gridjs-spread {
      cursor: default;
      box-shadow: none;
      background-color: #fff; }
    .gridjs-pagination .gridjs-pages button.gridjs-currentPage {
      background-color: #f7f7f7;
      font-weight: bold; }
    .gridjs-pagination .gridjs-pages button:last-child {
      border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
      border-top-right-radius: 6px;
      border-right: 1px solid #d2d6dc; }
    .gridjs-pagination .gridjs-pages button:first-child {
      border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
      border-top-left-radius: 6px; }

button.gridjs-sort {
  float: right;
  height: 24px;
  width: 13px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-x: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-size: contain; }
  button.gridjs-sort-neutral {
    opacity: 0.3;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
    background-position-y: center; }
  button.gridjs-sort-asc {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
    background-position-y: 35%;
    background-size: 10px; }
  button.gridjs-sort-desc {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
    background-position-y: 65%;
    background-size: 10px; }

button.gridjs-sort:focus {
  outline: none; }

table.gridjs-table {
  max-width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: left;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  table-layout: fixed; }

.gridjs-tbody {
  background-color: #fff; }

td.gridjs-td {
  border: 1px solid #e5e7eb;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-sizing: content-box; }

td.gridjs-td:first-child {
  border-left: none; }

td.gridjs-td:last-child {
  border-right: none; }

td.gridjs-message {
  text-align: center; }

th.gridjs-th {
  position: relative;
  color: #6b7280;
  background-color: #f9fafb;
  border: 1px solid #e5e7eb;
  border-top: none;
  padding: 14px 24px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: nowrap;
  outline: none;
  vertical-align: middle; }
  th.gridjs-th .gridjs-th-content {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    float: left; }
  th.gridjs-th-sort {
    cursor: pointer; }
    th.gridjs-th-sort .gridjs-th-content {
      width: calc(100% - 15px); }
  th.gridjs-th-sort:hover {
    background-color: #e5e7eb; }
  th.gridjs-th-sort:focus {
    background-color: #e5e7eb; }
  th.gridjs-th-fixed {
    position: sticky;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #e5e7eb; }
    @supports (-moz-appearance: none) {
      th.gridjs-th-fixed {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #e5e7eb; } }

th.gridjs-th:first-child {
  border-left: none; }

th.gridjs-th:last-child {
  border-right: none; }

.gridjs-tr {
  border: none; }
  .gridjs-tr-selected td {
    background-color: #ebf5ff; }

.gridjs-tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: 0; }

.gridjs *,
.gridjs :after,
.gridjs :before {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

.gridjs-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
  display: block;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-color: #e5e7eb; }

.gridjs-wrapper:nth-last-of-type(2) {
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px; }

.gridjs-search {
  float: left; }
  .gridjs-search-input {
    width: 250px; }

.gridjs-loading-bar {
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0.5; }
  .gridjs-loading-bar::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(204, 204, 204, 0) 0, rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.2) 20%, rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.5) 60%, rgba(204, 204, 204, 0));
    -webkit-animation: shimmer 2s infinite;
            animation: shimmer 2s infinite;
    content: ''; }

@-webkit-keyframes shimmer {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%); } }

@keyframes shimmer {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100%); } }

.gridjs-td .gridjs-checkbox {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer; }

.gridjs-resizable {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 5px; }
  .gridjs-resizable:hover {
    cursor: ew-resize;
    background-color: #9bc2f7; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=mermaid.css.map */

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  .gridjs-head button, .gridjs-footer button {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none; }
  
  .gridjs-temp {
    position: relative; }
  
  .gridjs-head {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 5px 1px; }
    .gridjs-head::after {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      clear: both; }
  
  .gridjs-head:empty {
    padding: 0;
    border: none; }
  
  .gridjs-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 2px;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0; }
  
  .gridjs-footer {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
    padding: 12px 24px;
    border-top: 1px solid #1a1814;
    background-color: #000;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(255,255,255, 0.1), 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(255,255,255, 0.26);
    border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-color: #1a1814; }
  
  .gridjs-footer:empty {
    padding: 0;
    border: none; }
  
  input.gridjs-input {
    outline: none;
    background-color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #2d2923;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px 13px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.45;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none; }
    input.gridjs-input:focus {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(106,66,12, 0.5);
      border-color: #643d08; }
  
  .gridjs-pagination {
    color: #c2bfbb; }
    .gridjs-pagination::after {
      content: '';
      display: block;
      clear: both; }
    .gridjs-pagination .gridjs-summary {
      float: left;
      margin-top: 5px; }
    .gridjs-pagination .gridjs-pages {
      float: right; }
      .gridjs-pagination .gridjs-pages button {
        padding: 5px 14px;
        border: 1px solid #2d2923;
        background-color: #000;
        border-right: none;
        outline: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
           -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
                user-select: none; }
      .gridjs-pagination .gridjs-pages button:focus {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(106,66,12, 0.5); }
      .gridjs-pagination .gridjs-pages button:hover {
        background-color: #080808;
        color: #c3bda8;
        outline: none; }
      .gridjs-pagination .gridjs-pages button:disabled,
      .gridjs-pagination .gridjs-pages button[disabled],
      .gridjs-pagination .gridjs-pages button:hover:disabled {
        cursor: default;
        background-color: #000;
        color: #948d7f; }
      .gridjs-pagination .gridjs-pages button.gridjs-spread {
        cursor: default;
        box-shadow: none;
        background-color: #000; }
      .gridjs-pagination .gridjs-pages button.gridjs-currentPage {
        background-color: #080808;
        font-weight: bold; }
      .gridjs-pagination .gridjs-pages button:last-child {
        border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
        border-top-right-radius: 6px;
        border-right: 1px solid #2d2923; }
      .gridjs-pagination .gridjs-pages button:first-child {
        border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
        border-top-left-radius: 6px; }
  
  button.gridjs-sort {
    float: right;
    height: 24px;
    width: 13px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-size: contain; }
    button.gridjs-sort-neutral {
      opacity: 0.3;
      background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
      background-position-y: center; filter: invert(100%);}
    button.gridjs-sort-asc {
      background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIGlkPSJDYXBhXzEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4IgoJIHdpZHRoPSIyOTIuMzYycHgiIGhlaWdodD0iMjkyLjM2MXB4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjkyLjM2MiAyOTIuMzYxIiBzdHlsZT0iZW5hYmxlLWJhY2tncm91bmQ6bmV3IDAgMCAyOTIuMzYyIDI5Mi4zNjE7IgoJIHhtbDpzcGFjZT0icHJlc2VydmUiPgo8Zz4KCTxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0yODYuOTM1LDE5Ny4yODdMMTU5LjAyOCw2OS4zODFjLTMuNjEzLTMuNjE3LTcuODk1LTUuNDI0LTEyLjg0Ny01LjQyNHMtOS4yMzMsMS44MDctMTIuODUsNS40MjRMNS40MjQsMTk3LjI4NwoJCUMxLjgwNywyMDAuOTA0LDAsMjA1LjE4NiwwLDIxMC4xMzRzMS44MDcsOS4yMzMsNS40MjQsMTIuODQ3YzMuNjIxLDMuNjE3LDcuOTAyLDUuNDI1LDEyLjg1LDUuNDI1aDI1NS44MTMKCQljNC45NDksMCw5LjIzMy0xLjgwOCwxMi44NDgtNS40MjVjMy42MTMtMy42MTMsNS40MjctNy44OTgsNS40MjctMTIuODQ3UzI5MC41NDgsMjAwLjkwNCwyODYuOTM1LDE5Ny4yODd6Ii8+CjwvZz4KPGc+CjwvZz4KPGc+CjwvZz4KPGc+CjwvZz4KPGc+CjwvZz4KPGc+CjwvZz4KPGc+CjwvZz4KPGc+CjwvZz4KPGc+CjwvZz4KPGc+CjwvZz4KPGc+CjwvZz4KPGc+CjwvZz4KPGc+CjwvZz4KPGc+CjwvZz4KPGc+CjwvZz4KPGc+CjwvZz4KPC9zdmc+");
      background-position-y: 35%;
      background-size: 10px; filter: invert(100%);}
    button.gridjs-sort-desc {
      background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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");
      background-position-y: 65%;
      background-size: 10px; filter: invert(100%);}
  
  button.gridjs-sort:focus {
    outline: none; }
  
  table.gridjs-table {
    max-width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: left;
    display: table;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    table-layout: fixed; }
  
  .gridjs-tbody {
    background-color: #000; }
  
  td.gridjs-td {
    border: 1px solid #1a1814;
    padding: 12px 24px;
    background-color: #000;
    box-sizing: content-box; }
  
  td.gridjs-td:first-child {
    border-left: none; }
  
  td.gridjs-td:last-child {
    border-right: none; }
  
  td.gridjs-message {
    text-align: center; }
  
  th.gridjs-th {
    position: relative;
    color: #6b7280;
    background-color: #060504;
    border: 1px solid #1a1814;
    border-top: none;
    padding: 14px 24px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
       -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    white-space: nowrap;
    outline: none;
    vertical-align: middle; }
    th.gridjs-th .gridjs-th-content {
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 100%;
      float: left; }
    th.gridjs-th-sort {
      cursor: pointer; }
      th.gridjs-th-sort .gridjs-th-content {
        width: calc(100% - 15px); }
    th.gridjs-th-sort:hover {
      background-color: #1a1814; }
    th.gridjs-th-sort:focus {
      background-color: #1a1814; }
    th.gridjs-th-fixed {
      position: sticky;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #1a1814; }
      @supports (-moz-appearance: none) {
        th.gridjs-th-fixed {
          box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #1a1814; } }
  
  th.gridjs-th:first-child {
    border-left: none; }
  
  th.gridjs-th:last-child {
    border-right: none; }
  
  .gridjs-tr {
    border: none; }
    .gridjs-tr-selected td {
      background-color: #140a00; }
  
  .gridjs-tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom: 0; }
  
  .gridjs *,
  .gridjs :after,
  .gridjs :before {
    box-sizing: border-box; }
  
  .gridjs-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(255,255,255, 0.1), 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(255,255,255, 0.26);
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
    display: block;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-color: #1a1814; }
  
  .gridjs-wrapper:nth-last-of-type(2) {
    border-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px; }
  
  .gridjs-search {
    float: left; }
    .gridjs-search-input {
      width: 250px; }
  
  .gridjs-loading-bar {
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.5; }
    .gridjs-loading-bar::after {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      transform: translateX(-100%);
      background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(51,51,51, 0) 0, rgba(51,51,51, 0.2) 20%, rgba(51,51,51, 0.5) 60%, rgba(51,51,51, 0));
      -webkit-animation: shimmer 2s infinite;
              animation: shimmer 2s infinite;
      content: ''; }
  
  @-webkit-keyframes shimmer {
    100% {
      transform: translateX(100%); } }
  
  @keyframes shimmer {
    100% {
      transform: translateX(100%); } }
  
  .gridjs-td .gridjs-checkbox {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    cursor: pointer; }
  
  .gridjs-resizable {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 5px; }
    .gridjs-resizable:hover {
      cursor: ew-resize;
      background-color: #643d08; }
  
}
```

output:

[image]

Source:
[burggraf](https://github.com/grid-js/gridjs/issues/115#issuecomment-1151543389)

Answer (score 0):

Assign classname to table,td or th as shown [here](https://gridjs.io/docs/config/className)

```
new Grid({
  data: [
    ['John', 'john@example.com', '(353) 01 222 3333'],
    ['Mark', 'mark@gmail.com',   '(01) 22 888 4444']
  ],
  className: {
    td: 'my-td-class',
    table: 'custom-table-class' 
  }
});
```

Then in css,

```
.my-td-class{
background-color: black;
}
 .custom-table-class{
background-color: black;
}
```

I managed to change my table's theme this way.
[image]